# Tuleap query cause performance issue

Tags: mysql, query-performance, tuleap

We are having almost 32000 ticket in tuleap on a single tracker,and the tracker is used by 100 users from different UserGroups and some of the users were mapped for multiple UserGroups.
Currently, we are having slow down issues. While we analyze the reason for slow performance. 
Users when search with personal search results(Saved) the issues occurs and the same works fine on the public search. 
Could you please suggest a fix for this issue.

Comment: You might have best results asking this on the tuleap forum. To get a useful answer here, please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ especially the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question to provide more information.

Comment: Please provide the SQL statement, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and any other relevant info about the problem.